# How can I back another person's question with evidence?

Tags: discussion

In [How does the Fed's stimulus push stocks markets higher?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/39030), author didn't cite any sources.

At [1:35](https://youtu.be/FL5LJ17Y7lg?t=95), Jeffrey Sachs claims what that author claims.

> [[Elizabeth Schulze :](https://www.cnbc.com/elizabeth-schulze/) ] How do you explain the difference between what's happening with
> the stock market right now and that economic picture that you
> painted? It's pretty grim, while, you know, stocks are positive for the year?

> [Sachs :] Clearly, the stock market is going up, in part because the Fed
> has pumped in 3 trillion dollars into the economy. **We know that if you pump in enough money, you can get asset
> prices to rise.**
> And so this is the playbook of 2008 and afterwards, and it is at
> work again.

> Partly the stock market simply doesn't capture the whole economy. The stock market is not the restaurants and the shops that are going out of business in large numbers.
> The stock market is Amazon and Apple and Microsoft and big enterprises, much more online. While the brick and mortar, smaller and medium enterprises are
> going broke. So we're not seeing in the stock market a snapshot of the whole economy.
> We're seeing a snapshot of the piece of the economy that is
> either persisting or doing well because it is online.

Can I add this to that question, to back it up with evidence? I can post a new question if you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don’t think you should post it as an another question as it would be duplicate then.

If you want you can add it as a hyperlink for the sentence where the user says he read about this somewhere with a direction to that article but even that might be problematic if user had a specific article in mind.

However, I don’t see any reason for putting direct quotes from that article to that question it would just unnecessarily make it longer and less clear and the question already works as is. Especially since it’s someone’s else’s question.

I think a better alternative altogether might be to just write a comment under the question about which articles had the user in mind and if this is one such example.